# How to specify Job DSL checkout timeout in Jenkins Git plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

Clone timeout can be specified using:

```
git {
    ...
    cloneTimeout(60)
}
```

where 60 is timeout is minutes. I read that checkout timeout can also be specified but I cannot find details. Both `checkoutTimeout(...)` and `timeout(...)` give an error.

**EDIT**

I can set the checkout timeout via Jenkins GUI (`Configuration` --> `SCM` --> `Git` --> `Additional Behaviors` --> `Advanced Checkout Behaviors` --> `Timeout`). I'd like to do the same in a Groovy script that generates Docker configurations for Jenkins:

```
...
public class DockerJob {
...
    multiscm {
        git {
            remote {
                url(...)
                branch(...)
                ...
            }
            shallowClone()
            cloneTimeout(60)
            // Add "checkout timeout" here...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in the Job Configuration through the Jenkins UI?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some experimentation, I found the solution shown below.

**RECAP**

Checkout timeout can be set via Jenkins GUI (`Configuration` --> `SCM` --> `Git` --> `Additional Behaviors` --> `Advanced Checkout Behaviors` --> `Timeout`). I'd like to do the same in a Groovy script that generates Docker configurations for Jenkins. The script already sets clone timeout.

```
...
public class DockerJob {
...
    multiscm {
        git {
            remote {
                url(...)
                branch(...)
                ...
            }
            shallowClone()
            cloneTimeout(60)
            // Add "checkout timeout" here...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
...
```

The obvious

```
...
// "Checkout timeout"
checkoutTimeout(60)
...
```

did not work. Setting timeouts in general

```
...
// "Checkout timeout"
timeout(60)
...
```

also did not work. Then comment on a web page lead to:

```
...
// "Checkout timeout"
extensions {
    checkoutOptions {
        timeout(60)
    }
}
...
```

that also did not work. Finally...

**SOLUTION**

```
...
public class DockerJob {
...
    multiscm {
        git {
            remote {
                url(...)
                branch(...)
                ...
            }
            shallowClone()
            cloneTimeout(60)
            // "Checkout timeout"
            configure { node ->
                node / 'extensions' << 'hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.CheckoutOption' {
                    timeout 60
                }
            }
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 18):

I had to change it like this with the pipeline as the *CheckoutOption* was not working for me

*extensions: [[**$class: 'CloneOption', timeout: 120**]]*

Full checkout code

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']],
            extensions: [[$class: 'CloneOption', timeout: 120]], gitTool: 'Default', 
            userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: key, url: repo]]
        ])
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using the workflow plugin and do something like this?

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'CheckoutOption', timeout: 100]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[]]])
```

Comment: For simplicity, I'd like a solution (for checkout timeout) similar to what is already present for clone timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Following checkout config works perfect for me in a jenkins pipeline script. We are using stash1 just like github as internal git server. Replace it with your own.

```
stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                echo "Running checkout stage"
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [
                    [name: "*/${params.branch}"]
                ], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [
                    [$class: 'CleanCheckout'], [$class: 'CloneOption', timeout: 30, shallow: true]
                ], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [
                    [credentialsId: 'ink_bot', url: "ssh://git@stash1.XYZ.com:7999/int_sparktp/${params.repo}.git"]
                ]])
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this extension works for me.

```
extensions: [[$class: 'CloneOption', timeout: 60]]
```